# Missing drivers after creating unallocated partition for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, partitioning, unallocated

after creating unallocated partition from c drive (first partitioning the drive then deleting it) to be used for ubuntu I encountered an error opening the cd drive in my hp pavillion dv6, repeated attempts to reinstall the driver have seemed successful but the drive gives the same error whenever you try to open it manually or through the computer. Is this due to deleting the partition I've made?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question:
What is 'c drive'? What are you trying to achieve?

Ubuntu installer lets you create partition for your OSs directly, no need to prepare them beforehand, if that was your goal.

Comment: I can't comment on your question as I don't have enough reputation points so I had to respond this way (ridiculous I know)

Comment: I meant the c:/ disk I apologize for that, but what I  'me trying to do is find out if anyone else has encountered similar errors (hardware drivers missing, cd drive errors) after creating unallocated memory on their hard drive.

Comment: So you created a new partition in Windows (I assume as they use c:/), right? Than you deleted the whole partition? And than your CD drive stopped working, correct? I'm just trying to figure out what are you doing:) Btw have you tried the Ubuntu installer (boot from Ubuntu LiveCD/USB and choose 'install')?

Comment: Yes exactly, I should specify that I'm asking for a friend and can't say if they've tried the installer, but now the cd drive can't open (it just gives an error message) so they install from the disk for the moment though I suppose I could get him to just use a flash drive with Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Alright now we are getting somewhere :) what's the error message btw? Some CD drives have small hole for servisman to open it even when turned off/unplugged etc. Ordinary pin should do the trick if you need to oped the drive. But LiveUSB should be a safe bet and it's faster than CD..